# Spring AMQP and Elasticsearch - aggregate messages

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, aggregate, spring-integration, spring-amqp

We have a consumer on some RabbitMQ queues which reads messages and then indexes this data in Elasticsearch. The implementation is done using spring-amqp. In order to increase our performance, we plan to aggregate the messages at the consumer level and do a bulk insert in Elasticsearch (this would really increase performance).

Do you have any sugestions on how to implement this? Also, another sensitive problem is how to handle responses. Each message has a "reply_to" header and we use an inbound gateway with a reply-channel, so for each message a response is supposed to be delivered.

I am thinking of using the aggregator from spring integration, with a release strategy based on a batch size and a period of time when the MessageGroupStore will expire (and of course the reaper). The inbound gateway has a task executor of 20 let's say and a prefetch count of 20 also. Whenever a request comes, the message will be added into the group store and when the canRelease() condition is ok, the reaper ot one of the threads that came with the request will do a bulk operation. But what I do with the other threads, which will have to wait for a response which will never come. Also, I don't know how to break the response for the big, aggregated message so each small request will have a response.

Another problem, how do I ack the messages? From what I read transactions will decrease performance on the RabbitMQ side, so I not that pleased of using the "tx-size" attribute. Also this attribute might do a wrong count if the timeout is too small.

Comment: Solution I found:replace inbound gateway with inbound and outbound channel adapters.Receive the message through an inbound channel adapter,the chain continues with an aggregator.From the aggregator, a service activator gets the bulk message, does it's job and the big response is added on a response channel. Here I have to break apart the big message into smaller ones and manually ack the messages. I need to take care also of keeping all the reply_to headers. After I have all the small response messages,I give them to an outbound channel adapter with routing-key-expression= headers["reply_to"].

Comment: I don't really know if this can be done with SI and spring-amqp though. I have to enrich somehow the headers for the aggregated message or manually build them in the aggregate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question regarding consumer and aggregator:

The config to consume messages from AMQP and aggregate.
The aggregate strategy is based on the Transction commit:

```
<amqp:inbound-channel-adapter queue-names="myQueue"
                                  transaction-manager="transactionManager"
                                  channel-transacted="true"
                                  channel="aggregateChannel"
                                  advice-chain="aggregatorReaperAdvice"
                                  concurrent-consumers="4"
                                  tx-size="100"/>

<aggregator input-channel="aggregateChannel" output-channel="storeChannel"
                expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
                correlation-strategy-expression="T(Thread).currentThread().id"
                release-strategy-expression="^[payload.equals(@AGGREGATOR_RELEASE_MARK)] != null"
                expression="?[!payload.equals(@AGGREGATOR_RELEASE_MARK)].![payload]"/>
```

The `ReaperAdvice` (Groovy code):

```
@Service
class AggregatorReaperAdvice implements MethodBeforeAdvice, InitializingBean {

    private static final TRANSACTION_RESOURCE_MARK = 'TRANSACTION_RESOURCE_MARK'

    public static final AGGREGATOR_RELEASE_MARK = 'AGGREGATOR_RELEASE_MARK'

    MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate

    @Autowired
    MessageChannel aggregateChannel

    @Override
    void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull aggregateChannel, "aggregateChannel must not be null"
        messagingTemplate = new MessagingTemplate(aggregateChannel)
    }

    @Override
    void before(Method method, Object[] args, Object target) {
        if (!TransactionSynchronizationManager.hasResource(AggregatorReaperAdvice)) {
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(AggregatorReaperAdvice, TRANSACTION_RESOURCE_MARK)
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {

                @Override
                void beforeCommit(boolean readOnly) {
                    messagingTemplate.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(AGGREGATOR_RELEASE_MARK).build())
                }

                @Override
                void afterCompletion(int status) {
                    TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(AggregatorReaperAdvice)
                }

            })
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if it isn't clear.

All other question, will be addressed soon.

For `manual ack` you can use `channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, true);` - to `ack` on the last `deliveryTag` for all previous messages.

For the `headers["reply_to"]` case... I think you should provide custom `AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor` for the `aggregator` and kill two birds: the cumulative result of aggregator and iteration over `MessageGroup.getMessages()` to send each of them for the reply process to the provided `MessageChannel`. It is a quick solution for your case.

Something similar but more loosely-coupled solution maybe based on the result from aggregator and its `MessageGroupStore`, where you extract `correlationKey` to retrieve group and its messages to do the desired `reply` logic. In this case you shouldn't remove group from store with aggregator, but manually after that group retrieval.

Comment: Hi Artem. Thank you very much for your response. So my idea looks ok to you from what I understand:d. As you correctly mentioned, the  AggregatorReaperAdvice code is not really clear to me. Can you please explain the point of transactions here? I don't like setting the tx-size because of the following scenario.If I have prefetch-count=tx-size=100(prefetch0count<tx-size is not good) and my service died and many large messages(maybe 1 MB of data) are persisted on Rabbit, when my service restarts a lot of messages will be added into the RAM and I might have an OutOfMemory(10consumers*100*1Mb=1Gb)

Comment: Well, my `AggregatorReaperAdvice` is applied to the `Listener` process and it will be within TX. It registers `TXSync`, which is tied with TX and does artificial aggregator `release` sending some `MARK` message. Having this I aggregate exactly `tx-size` messages or less and within TX. Since you worry about RAMyou can play with that `tx-size` and `concurency`. So, there won't be more listener processes than you allow for it. You should be sure that you do other downstream flow within that listener Thread to block it and don't allow to start a new listener task.

Comment: Sorry for being insistent, but I have 3 more questions. 1)Any advantage of having the correlation strategy based on the thread id? With 4 consumers, I will have 1 _SimpleMessageStore_ with 4 _SimpleMessageGroup_. 2)If an exception is being thrown the transaction will rollback. If I have configured an errorchannel with a service activator(we always return a response saying what exception was thrown and we don't want to redeliver the message), will I still receive the failedMessage here?I don't know for sure, but I think that the message will be requeued.

Comment: 3)How can I implement a mechanism of returning responses on different reply channels and maybe Rabbit queues for successful action and failed ones? I was thinking of having two headers in the  original message, one for _successful_reply_to_ and one for _errors_reply_to_

Comment: 1) true. 2) No, TX is roll backed only if you rethrow Exception from that error-channel service-activator. 3) I'd say there is just enough to have only one `reply_to` header, but build the target `routing_key` based on the logic - successful or error.

Comment: Hi again @Artem Bilan. You have not really answered my question 1) :d, about the advantages of having the correlation strategy based on thread id. I looked at he code and saw this line _this.lockRegistry.obtain(UUIDConverter.getUUID(correlationKey).toString())_, which tells me that the consumer threads won't have to wait to acquire a lock, since each thread will have it's own lock. Is this correct? From my  understanding, this is the advantage. Also, if I don't do this correlation, then all the consumer threads will have to wait to acquire the lock, which will decrease performance.

Comment: Since my sample has `concurrent-consumers="4"` it assumes that I may have 4 concurrent Threads to consume messages from Queue. From other side we have `tx-size="100"` option. I mean that each concurrent Thread will be wrapped with TX and and do its consumption until 100 or `no more messages`. And commits its TX. Our listener just sends messages to the Aggregator. If we know that we can have a group of those 100 messages we can simply correlate them with current `thread id`, because we don't have any other option to choose for correlation. And yes: our threads don't wait on their own lock.